# Toast messages disappearing very fast

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, handler, toast, android-toast

In `onResume()` method, I use `new Handler()` to create alert dialog, and from my alert dialog `onClick` method to call Wifi system settings Activity and display `Toast` after it.

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showDialog();
        } }); 
}


private void showDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
    builder.setMessage("Go to wifi settings and display Toast over it");
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch(which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    Intent intent = newIntent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS); 
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    String toastText = "Display Toast";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                 case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    dialog.cancel();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };


                builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", dialogClickListener);
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",dialogClickListener);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.show();
}
```

Toast message disappears immediately after Wifi system settings Activity starts.
Toast should last for 3.5 seconds. I've seen my toast disappearing in 1 second. So, I decided to test it on new hello world project, `onCreate` method, with next code lines:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 1);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Display Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Now, Toasts behave normally, lasting for 3.5 seconds. Then I tested Toast message on original project again, but this time, I put Toast message in `onCreate` method. Started my app, fast clicked on alert dialog button, and Toast still disappears immediately after opening Wifi system settings.
I suspect this is because I used Handler + dialog onClick to call startActivityForResult(Intent, 1). Maybe it's thread problem, my phone(Nokia 2.2, Android 11) problem or something else, however, it's weird Toast behavior. If you have solution to this, or any suggestions I can try, let me know, I will appreciate it.

Edit: found this in my logcat. 2021-07-31 23:16:53.165 1025-1568/? W/NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.example.android token=android.os.BinderProxy@afaf53e did some research and it seems like Android system activity mistakes my Toasts for custom made Toast(custom Toasts are blocked since android 11) without reason to do that. I will try stuff a little longer, but for now, my conclusion is that this is bug on new Toast behaviors.

Comment: It's not a thread problem. I think it's due to toast behaviour changes of 11.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya Could be, I will check out on older Android version

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the switch() With if-else and see if it's working or not. Maybe the `break;` statement is manipulating the Toast (It shouldn't or maybe the problem can be somewhere else, but just give it a try :) ).

Comment: Sadly, didn't fix it, but it was definitely worth a shot.

Comment: Then it's definitely an Android 11 problem. It changes the Toast behavior when the app is in the background. You are opening the WIfi settings and at that time, your app goes to the background for a while. That's the reason the Toast gets canceled.
Have you checked it in different below Android 11 devices?

Comment: Tested on bluestacks 5, it works fine. Yeah you are right, Toast is blocked if app is in background, but my app should be considered foreground because it's last activity was closed 1 second ago. Could be wrong, but I think that dialog or Toast is misbehaving.